# How to upgrade GTK 3.10 to GTK 3.14 on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, unity, gnome, upgrade, gtk

How to upgrade GTK 3.10 to 3.14 on ubuntu 14.04? Most of the discussions provide an answer in which they replace the **Unity** desktop with the GNOME desktop.
**I want to do this upgrade without adding any other desktop environment**.
Kindly provide step by step method if possible.

P.S.: this upgrade is required for installing ARC GTK Theme.

Comment: You'll probably install a version of a Ubuntu that supports 3.14 then (i.e. 15.04) - alternately, you could work your way through redoing versions of the relevant packages from source so they don't break 14.04. Also, as far as I remember, installing gtk 3.14 in 14.10 (and probably 3.12 in 14.04) breaks Unity, so probably would make a bigger mess trying to install the available 3.14 packages in 14.04.

Comment: Now I don't want to risk unity's stability. I will probably upgrade my distribution now

Comment: @Wilf: Could you please convert that to an answer so that schmucks like me who go around hunting for unanswered questions don't have to look at this one any more?  **;-)**  (And I'll upvote if you drop me a note and it's a good one too!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll probably need install a version of a Ubuntu that supports 3.14 then (i.e. 15.04).

Alternately, you could work your way through redoing versions of the relevant packages from source so they don't break 14.04 (probably very difficult), or redo the theme to work better with older versions

Also, installing [Gnome/gtk 3.14 in 14.10](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/10/how-to-install-gnome-314-in-ubuntu.html) (and probably [3.12 in 14.04](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/05/how-to-install-gnome-312-in-ubuntu.html)) with the available GNOME PPAs [[1]](https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/ubuntu/gnome3-staging) [[2]](https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/ubuntu/gnome3) breaks Unity, so probably would make a bigger mess trying to install the available 3.14 packages in 14.04.